# same mysql database gives different fulltext index search results on 2 different servers

Tags: mysql, innodb, fulltext-index

I have the same database running on 2 instances of mysql 5.7.20 (one on ubuntu, one on macosx). The osx-version gives sensible results in the InnoDB-fulltext search (e.g. searching for "facts and figures" gives 3 results on top with a relevance score of 11.5, 6.5, 6.5 and "Facts and Figures" in the title).

On the Linux-System searching for "Facts and Figures" in the *same* database gives completely different results with relevance scores starting with 44 - and very weird results. The ones found on macosx on top appear on position 20+. Even a fresh dump of the database behaves like this.

The mysql-configuration is similar (innodb_ft_token_size, etc.) only differing in paths and the like. Has anyone any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: "and the like": That is a very broad description. Please add more details about the differences between your two servers. Same table setup? Same data? Double check collations for `varchar` columns?

Comment: differing variables are directories, expire_log_days, innodb_numa_interleave, innodb_open_files, innodb_use_native_aio,  key_buffer_size, lower_case_file_system, lower_case_table_names, max_allowed_packet, max_binlog_size - but nothing that has (at least to my knowledge) any connection to the fulltext-index. Apart from this it is the database dump taken from the linux machine and imported to the osx-machine. characterset and collation are the same (utf8_general_ci)